# Silabs CP210x driver for mac not working. - Feb 21

Tags: macos, driver, kernel-extension

This is an attempt to get the latest.(on this issue)
This driver allows a usb to act as a serial port.

On mac-catalina, the driver loads something into the library-extensions fold. But nothing is loaded into the system-library-extensions folder.

It's a kext file, and I've tried to load it manually, and using kextdrop type programs, and nothing works.

If anyone, by chance, has the kext files needed for both extension folders, signed-notarized-and ready to kextload, please send them, this might work.

Or any solution is appreciated.

I'm trying to plug in an arduino thing.

Regards

Comment: Which particular *"Arduino thing"*? Maybe there is a CH340 or FT232 equivalent?

Comment: Alright, I deleted the driver, using the supplied uninstaller, and now mac catalina is "seeing" CP210x devices.  The driver is not loaded, but it is working fine.  So, I guess CP210x is now part of Mac OS.  And that's fine.